# what does 'cgi.parse_qs' mean

Tags: python

i find this code :

```
def _oauth_parse_response(body):
    p = cgi.parse_qs(body, keep_blank_values=False)
```

but i don't know  what is mean

thanks

Answer (score 5):

It means "look on the `cgi` object for an attribute called `parse_qs`, and call it as a function with `body` as a positional argument and `keep_blank_values` as a keyword argument with the value of `False`".

For the definition of `cgi` look further up, but it probably is the stdlib module [of the same name](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html).

Answer (score 4):

[docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org) has an excellent search engine, which will show you [this](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/cgi.html?highlight=parse_qs#cgi.parse_qs):

> This function is deprecated in this
>   module. Use [urllib.parse.parse_qs()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)
>   instead. It is maintained here only
>   for backward compatibility.

and once you follow the link, you see:

> Parse a query string given as a string
>   argument (data of type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded).
>   Data are returned as a dictionary. The
>   dictionary keys are the unique query
>   variable names and the values are
>   lists of values for each name.

and so on.

Much as I may like getting easy rep for answering absolutely trivial questions that anybody with a pulse should have zero trouble answering for themselves, maybe with some help from today's reasonably powerful search engines, some questions are really *too* easy to answer -- the stackoverflow equivalent of shooting sitting birds.  You're not a newbie here -- why not, and I'm going to suggest an absolutely revolutionary strategy!, make the microscopic effort of doing your own searches and asking questions when there **is** something worth asking?

Answer (score 3):

[Parses a query string into a dictionary.](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/node563.html)

[Deprecated in python >= 2.6.](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_qs)